# mongoose and cloudinary: how to use the public_id to find the file?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, cloudinary

I'm using the following code to find all documents:

```
const getAllCv = async (req, res) => {
    
    CV.find({}, function(err, res){
        const getResponseFromMongoDb = {};
        res.forEach(function(index){
            getResponseFromMongoDb[index] = index;
        })
        console.log(getResponseFromMongoDb.cv_file);
    });
    //console.log(getResponseFromMongoDb);
}
```

A sample response is:

```
  {
    _id: 60597b9454893a1a9c16f3c5,
    name: 'John Doe',
    contact: '12345678912',
    email: 'john@gmail.com',
    shipType: 'BULK CARRIER',
    rank: 'CHIEEF ENGINEER',
    cv_file: 'lm3iyxn0pbu9tuheicfr',
    date: 2021-03-23T05:24:36.906Z,
    __v: 0
  }
```

I need to keep track of the entire response and the cv_file individually. The cv file contains the public_id for cloudinary which I'm using as my file storage system.

So I need something like

```
const cv_file_id = res.cv_file -------> to find the fileassociated with the name/contact
## find the file from cloudinary
```

And finally make on single response that'll have name, contact, email, shipType, rank, buffer of the file that I can use for my admin dashboard.

Now how can I make a separate query from my existing response and make on single json response?

and is my approach correct or is there any other easier method for doing so?

N.B: My admin dashboard is in backend so I'm using ejs as templating engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty simple. All you have to do is append the public_id to the URL of cloudinary as per their format.

---

Here is a sample response from cloudinary after image upload (I have omitted a lot of fields to keep the answer precise):-

```
{
  "public_id": "eneivicys42bq5f2jpn2",
  "version": 1570979139,
  "width": 1000,
  "height": 672,
  "format": "jpg",
  "resource_type": "image",
  "type": "upload",
  "placeholder": false,
  "url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1570979139/eneivicys42bq5f2jpn2.jpg",
  "secure_url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1570979139/eneivicys42bq5f2jpn2.jpg",
  "access_mode": "public",
  "original_filename": "sample",
}
```

Full sample response [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#sample_response)

As you can see, public_id is the last parameter in the URL of the image(given in URL and secure_url fields) along with other stuff like version, image format, cloud name, etc.

**So in conclusion**:-

Either you can construct the complete URL using version, public_id, cloud name, etc. Or just store the secure_url from the response with your JSON document.

All you have to do is send the same response to the client-side and fetch the image/file there itself. You may provide the admin with the link itself or as `<img src={url_of_file} />`

Comment: so basaically I need the url not the public_id right? The thing is I don't need to preview the file(pdf in my case) I only need the name and a download button

Comment: Yes. You can provide the link to cloudinary itself(secure_url in response) and yes in my opinion it would be better to store secure_url instead of public_id because to construct the link you need multiple information like version, cloud name, etc so it is better to store secure_url itself and redirect the admin to the URL or download from there.